# Linux - Change keyboard configuration at kdm

Tags: linux, keyboard

I'm on Arch linux now but at every restart at the login screen, I seem to be in Azerty when I need a Qwerty keyboard, how I change that ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your rc.conf file (/etc folder) look for the line KEYMAP="" and change the  to us or whatever layout you want

you can find the available layouts in "/usr/share/kbd/keymaps" and the sub folders, just use the name minux the .map.gz

**Example**

if you want to use "/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz" then just add "us" to the config file