# Linux: change keyboard layout on the fly

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

How can you change the keyboard layout (to QWERTY from QWERTZ) on the fly from a Linux shell?

I found [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/47127/linux-change-keyboard-configuration-at-kdm), but the answer was to edit a config file, which is not so easy when you're using a Live CD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[setxkbmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setxkbmap)

Comment: I never said I was running X... I am actually, but do you know how to do it from the console?

Answer (score 8):

kbdconfig or loadkeys

That's how we used to do it.  I don't know if they're still supported; I'll check next time I've got Knoppix running.

Comment: loadkeys works on Arch. Can't use setxdbmap because I don't have X installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any tool that changes keymap on-the-fly, but in at least debian it is possible to edit `/etc/default/console-setup` with your preferred map, and make the system reflect those changes by issuing `/etc/init.d/hal restart`.

Answer (score 1):

On recent systems, if you have root privileges, you can use the following:

```
localectl set-keymap en_GB
```

for the virtual console keyboard, and

```
localectl set-x11-keymap en_GB
```

for the X11 layout.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

Go in the menu and add your layout to keyboard:

*System->Preferences->Keyboard*, where choose *Layouts* tab and add your language (the default is the one chosen at installation time). Then you can press the *Layout Options...* button, and look in *Key(s) to change layout* for the hot keys that changes the Keyboard layout. For me it is *Shift+Caps Lock*.

Hope to help.

N.B. I'm running CentOS 6.2 with GNOME interface.

Comment: I wasn't running Gnome (or KDE either).

Answer (score -1):

It may look hacky but it works like a charm:

```
setxkbmap -layout ru && setxkbmap -layout ru,us
setxkbmap -layout us && setxkbmap -layout us,ru
```

To force switch:

```
setxkbmap -layout ru && setxkbmap -layout us && setxkbmap -layout us,ru
```

You can program your loop if you need.