# Keyboard Configuration File

Tags: keyboard, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 12.

During install, I accidentally selected English (UK) instead of English (US) for my keyboard layout. I can change the keyboard layout in the settings, but I have to do it everytime I logon. I'd like to make it the default. Does anyone know where the configuration file for the keyboard layout is? I tried

```
~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/accessibility/keyboard/%gconf.xml
```

but it doesn't have it. I've also tried looking in `/etc`, in both `gnome`, `kbd`, and `gconf`, with not luck. Also had a look at `inputrc` file. No keymap options there. Then I had a look in `/usr/share`, at `gnome-control-center`, `gnome`, it might be there, but I can't find any configurations that pertain to keyboard layouts.

I know that the keyboard layout is still in English (UK) whenever I logon, because my password is wrong. It took me sometime to figure out where the correct keys were, I almost re-installed. I want the keymap to be US before I logon.

Similiar to this question: https://superuser.com/a/47945/89743. However, I don't have an `/etc/rc.conf` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can re-configure the system level keyboard layout using:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

from a terminal sesssion.

Comment: Thanks! You're a champ! By the way, when tweaking most applications, will `dpkg-reconfigure` work? Is the "preferences" menu entry for most applications simply a frontend for dpkg-reconfigure?

Comment: @SamuelTan When you install packages, you are often presented with a bit of configuration you need to do to set up the package. dpkg-reconfigure lets you re-run that config. This is system level, whereas the preference menu in an app is almost always user specific - an ordinary user cannot change system level configuration.